# Compare two files' columns

Tags: text-processing

File1:

```
judi /export/home 76
judi /usr 83
```

File2:

```
judi /export/home 79
judi /usr 82
```

if COLUMN3 of File2 is greater that COLUMN3 of File1, the command should print File2's line; for example, for the files above, the command should print:

```
judi /export/home 79
```

And not:

```
judi /usr 82
```

Comment: Are you interested in knowing how to compare the two files using Ubuntu or on how to write a program to do this?

Comment: I am interested to write a program to do this, may be a awk one liner

Comment: In your files are only two columns

Comment: three columns @A.B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{x[NR]=$3}{if($3>x[FNR]){print}}' File1 File2
```

- `NR==FNR{x[NR]=$3}`: if the current record number is equal to the current file record number (i.e. we're processing the first file), assigns the value of the third field to `x[NR]`;
- `{if($3>x[FNR]){print}}`: if the third field is greater than `x[FNR]`, prints the record.

```
% cat File1
judi /export/home 76
judi /usr 83
% cat File2
judi /export/home 79
judi /usr 82
% awk 'NR==FNR{x[NR]=$3}{if($3>x[FNR]){print}}' File1 File2
judi /export/home 79
```

Comment: Thanks very much @kos - : awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}$3>a[$1$2]&&a[$1$2]{print $0}' file1 file2 this one liner helps

Comment: @judi I missunderstood the question. Updating it, but what should happen if there are only 2 columns (for example like in the your example files' last lines)?

Comment: Just a small background, I have a defined threshold values for the system mount points like / /opt /usr /var in File1. I am exporting the current usage values to File2, I am using both file format as same, both file will have 3 columns, the rows may vary based on the mount points

Comment: @judi I confused the prompt after the files for lines of the files themselves, check the updated answer